# addClass()/removeClass() Transition Causes Split-Second Position Jump in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

What would cause the `addClass()`/`removeClass()` attributes to break a fluid transition?

Here is the current script I am working with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var o = 0;
  $("a.lbimg > img.lb-click").click(function() {
    var s = $("body");
    o = $(window).scrollTop(), s.css("position", "fixed"), s.css("top", "-" + o + "px"), s.css("background-position", "0 -" + o + "px"), s.addClass("no-scroll"), $("#lb-view").addClass("target");
  }), $("#lb-controls").on("click", function() {
    var s = $("body");
    s.css("position", ""), s.css("background-position", ""), o = $(window).scrollTop(o), s.removeClass("no-scroll"), $("#lb-view").removeClass("target");
  });
});
```

It's a bit hard to explain; however, this does seem to be a Safari-specific issue.

This is the main issue: when a photo is clicked on, it opens an image in a lightbox window. Then, upon closing the window, the `body` position jumps/shifts for only a split second before it adjusts back to the current window scroll position. Essentially, it breaks the function's visible fluidity.

Here is a snippet of the kind of CSS I am working with:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: -7;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

img {
  z-index: 1;
}

a.lbimg {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
}

a.lbimg img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.lb-click {
  height: auto;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -8;
}

.lbimg-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 45px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#lb-controls {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5;
}

#lb-close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#lb-close:before,
#lb-close:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#lb-close:before {
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 14px;
}

#lb-close:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
}

.customlightbox.target {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 4;
}

.customlightbox.target,
.customlightbox.target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox.target~#lb-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#lb-controls #lb-close:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#lb-controls #lb-close:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Any input on this?

Comment: I see no jump MacOS version 10.13.3 (17D102); Safari Version 11.0.3 (13604.5.6)

Comment: Ok, well that might explain the issue. I am going to test this on an updated system then. Was this some kind of bug that was recently fixed?

Comment: Don't know... just looked at your demo (which looks nice :-)

Comment: Have you tried setting background-origin? The browser may be confused about the initial position of the background. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, so I should apply this to the `body` then?

Comment: You set the `background-size` and `background-repeat` properties within the `html,bocy` CSS declaration. Perhaps there. It is unlikely to change anything, but worth a shot.

Comment: Didn't seem to resolve anything. Would actually like to get this fixed without the incentive of updating, since it seems like something that should be able to work... Plus, there's no guarantee that all visitors that come to my site will be updated to the latest version of MacOS/Safari.

Comment: My instinct is it has to do with the use of `scrollTop()` to set the `background-position` between `""` (inherit) and ` 0 -(scrollTop())` : bouncing between these two is pinging me. Afraid I can't help.

Comment: @RandyCasburn That’s ok, thanks for your suggestions. I’ll see what I can do from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have marked an answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101640/9214076. Also, I've applied this answer, and updated the original question here: [How to Make a Fixed Element Stay Relative to the Current Top Scroll Position?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49101033/9214076).