# How to Make a Fixed Element Stay Relative to the Current Top Scroll Position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, fixed

**Original Question:**

I have a function which opens an overlaying, `fixed`-positioned element when prompted, and I am trying to figure out how to be able to open this at the current `top` position, instead of jumping to the top of the page (`top: 0`) every time the `.no-scroll` class is active.

Here is the progress I've made, thus far:

```
var o = 0;
$("img.click").click(function() {
  var s = $("html, body");
  o = $(window).scrollTop(), s.css("position", "fixed"), s.css("background-position", "0 -" + o + "px");
  var i = $(this).attr("src");
  s.find("#img-open").attr("src", i), s.addClass("no-scroll"), $("#img-view").addClass("target");
});
```

And I've additionally applied a `.no-scroll` class to the `html`, and `body` tags:

```
html {
  height: initial;
}

body {
  height: auto;
}

body.no-scroll,
html.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

---

**Update (Applied Answer to Snippet + Additional Notes):**

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101640/9214076), I was able to adjust a few additional things:

1. No need for a `no-scroll` class on the `html` tag. Therefore, it was removed.
2. I added `preventDefault()` to the `touchmove` touch event, which keeps the `body` background content from scrolling on mobile browsers like iOS Safari, (as of 2018).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.lbimg > img.lb-click").click(function() {
    $("#lb-view").addClass("target");
    var o = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = o;
    $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
  $(".lbimg-wrap, #lb-controls").on("click", function(s) {
    $("#lb-view").removeClass("target");
    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
    $('body').unbind('touchmove');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: auto;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
  background: #808080;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

p.content {
  color: white;
}

img {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-wrap {
  display: block;
}

.img-wrap img {
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
}

a.lbimg {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
}

a.lbimg img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.lb-click {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.lbimg-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 47px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  border-color: white;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#lb-controls {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color: white;
  z-index: 3;
}

#lb-close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#lb-close:before,
#lb-close:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#lb-close:before {
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 14px;
}

#lb-close:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
}

.customlightbox.target {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.customlightbox.target,
.customlightbox.target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox.target~#lb-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#lb-controls #lb-close:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#lb-controls #lb-close:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <p class="content">
    Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll.
  </p>

  <div class="img-wrap">
    <a class="lbimg">
      <img class="lb-click" src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/8b1b8cbb2b963ab64eb2341f608638bf/tumblr_p4wbo7ZLJS1qccr26o1_1280.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="lb-view">
      <div class="lbimg-wrap">
        <img class="lb-animate" id="lbimg-open" src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/8b1b8cbb2b963ab64eb2341f608638bf/tumblr_p4wbo7ZLJS1qccr26o1_1280.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lb-controls" class="lb-animate">
      <a id="lb-close" class="lb-animate"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="content">
    Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll.
  </p>

</body>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @KoshVery Ok, I have just provided a snippet with my original post.

Comment: There's an image between the 'Content to scroll' paragraphs. This is so that the position jump can be observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a.lbimg > img.lb-click").click(function() {
    $("#lb-view").addClass("target");
    var o = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    $('html, body').addClass('no-scroll');
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = o;
  });

  $(".lbimg-wrap, #lb-controls").on("click", function(s) {
      $("#lb-view").removeClass("target");
      $('html, body').removeClass('no-scroll');
  });
  
});
```

```css
html {
  height: initial;
}

body {
  height: auto;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
  background: #808080;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body.no-scroll,
html.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

p.content {
  color: white;
}

img {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-wrap {
  display: block;
}

.img-wrap img {
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
}

a.lbimg {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
}

a.lbimg img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.lb-click {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.lbimg-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 47px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#lb-controls {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  opacity: .7;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7) !important;
  z-index: 3;
}

#lb-close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#lb-close:before,
#lb-close:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#lb-close:before {
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 14px;
}

#lb-close:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
}

.customlightbox.target {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.customlightbox.target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox.target~#lb-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#lb-controls #lb-close:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#lb-controls #lb-close:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <p class="content">
    Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll.
  </p>

  <div class="img-wrap">
    <a class="lbimg">
      <img class="lb-click" src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/8b1b8cbb2b963ab64eb2341f608638bf/tumblr_p4wbo7ZLJS1qccr26o1_1280.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="lb-view">
      <div class="lbimg-wrap">
        <img class="lb-animate" id="lbimg-open" src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/8b1b8cbb2b963ab64eb2341f608638bf/tumblr_p4wbo7ZLJS1qccr26o1_1280.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lb-controls" class="lb-animate">
      <a id="lb-close" class="lb-animate"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="content">
    Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content
    to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll. Content to scroll.
  </p>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is looking good. Is there any reason why the `#lb-controls` is not closing the window?

Comment: Great, all fixed indeed! A final question to run by you... Will this be compatible on a mobile browser, such as Safari iOS?

Comment: Actually, when I open this in the Safari iOS browser, the `body.no-scroll` class is scrollable. Is there any way to restrict this?

Comment: Don't mind the additional comments, I should have included them in my original question. So I made sure to mark this as the solution. Thank you!

Comment: @nrweb, Sorry, I could not reproduce it in iOS Safari. It does not scroll, but overscrolls only. To get rid of overscroll effect, add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:auto` to `.no-scroll`

Comment: Thanks so much for your informative answers. They help me a lot!